Error while Replacing Org Symbols with LaTeX/PDF Commands in Emacs
I'm working on customizing the export of Org-mode files to LaTeX/PDF in Emacs. Specifically, I need to replace Org checklist symbols with custom LaTeX commands. The goal is to transform [ ] into \checkbox and [X] into \checkedbox when exporting to PDF.
Here’s the Emacs Lisp code I’m using for this transformation:
;; Define the custom checklist symbols in LaTeX
(defun my-org-latex-checklist-filter (text backend info)
  "Replace Org checklist symbols with custom LaTeX symbols."
  (when (org-export-derived-backend-p backend 'latex)
    ;; Ensure that LaTeX commands are properly escaped
    (let ((checkbox-replacement "\\\\checkbox")
          (checkedbox-replacement "\\\\checkedbox"))
      ;; Perform replacements
      (replace-regexp-in-string "\\[ \\]" checkbox-replacement
        (replace-regexp-in-string "\\[X\\]" checkedbox-replacement text)))))

;; Add the custom filter to the export process
(add-hook 'org-export-filter-final-output-functions
          'my-org-latex-checklist-filter)

The issue I’m encountering is an error message: "Invalid use of '\' in replacement text."
I’m unsure whether this is due to incorrect use of replace-regexp-in-string or if there might be a simpler way to achieve this transformation.
My Questions:

Is my use of replace-regexp-in-string correct, especially regarding escaping backslashes in the replacement text?
Are there alternative methods to perform these replacements more effectively?

Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated!
I’m trying to customize the export process in Emacs Org-mode to replace checklist symbols with LaTeX commands. Specifically, I want [ ] to be replaced with \checkbox and [X] to be replaced with \checkedbox in the final PDF output. However, I’m encountering an error related to the use of backslashes in the replacement text. I’m looking for guidance on whether my current approach with replace-regexp-in-string is correct and if there are any alternative methods or best practices for achieving this transformation effectively.

Might be better suited for https://emacs.stackexchange.com/
